# Nodejs server only responds to requests on devices on different network

Tags: node.js, https

So I've written a Node.js API, and have port forwarded both the 443 and 80 ports on my machine.  When I run the server, get and posts requests on devices on the same network through a browser timeout, but when I run those requests through either Postman or devices on a different network, it works.  When I am making the requests, I am using the IP that is available on IPChicken, which is my public IP.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: I'm guessing that when making the request to your public IP address from within the private network, it doesn't go through the port forwarding because the request isn't coming from outside the local network.  Not sure how one would solve that.  You can use the local IP address to access locally as a work-around.

Comment: How do I change the IP for my requests if it's on the same network?  Or is there a way to port forward local requests?

Comment: Well, from Postman on your local network, you just substitute the actual local IP address and actual local port of the target server in place of the domain as in `http://192.168.1.14:3000/somePath`.

Comment: It's funny because Postman works with my public IP on the same network

Comment: Well, then what exactly doesn't work from the local network?  Please be specific and show code and describe configuration if possible.

Comment: browser requests from the local network using the public IP don't work.  Postman requests from the local network using the public IP do.  Public IP requests from other networks work on browser.